# Standardize Pearson correlation coefficient 0-1

Tags: r, correlation, standardized

In my data I have a vector which is a measure of correlation between my observations that goes from -1 to 1. Because of substantive theoretical reasons I want to bound my measure of correlation from 0 to 1. Hence, a correlation of -1 should become 0 and a correlation of 1 should remain 1. Of course, absolute values or squaring will not make the job, as a negative correlation of -1 would become 1 which is not what I want.

Do you know how I can do this?
here is a dataset similar to my own.

```
 df <- data.frame("Reporter" = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), "competitor" = c("Africa","Africa", "Africa","Africa"), "Year" = c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000), "export similarity" = runif(4, min=-1, max= 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: `x = (x+1)/2` should do it

Comment: Were you looking for a correlation estimator that returns non-negative values only, or to just post-process the estimate into being non-negative?

Answer (score 1):

What you described is not uniquely defined, but `pmax` may be what you want:

```
df$export.similarity
# [1] -0.84002878 -0.75895521  0.09776857  0.38756309
pmax(df$export.similarity, 0)
# [1] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.09776857 0.38756309
```

Comment: @Alessandro, did it help?